# Make extension of a generic Objective-C class

Tags: swift, objective-c, generics, realm

How to refer to a generic in an ObjC extension? The following code yelds a

```
Extension of a generic Objective-C class cannot access the class's generic parameters at runtime
```

this code should convert `RLMResults<T>` into `[T]`

```
extension RLMResults {

    @objc func toArray<RLMObjectType>() -> [RLMObjectType] {
        var array = [RLMObjectType]()
        for result in self {
            array.append(result)
        }
        return array
    }

}
```

Definition of RLMResult in ObjC

```
@interface RLMResults<RLMObjectType> : NSObject<RLMCollection, NSFastEnumeration>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can't you just use the Swift version of Realm, where you have the `Results<T>` type, that you can just convert to an array by using `Array(someResults)`?

Comment: This is an existing app that uses the ObjC Realm

Comment: Well as the error says, Swift doesn't know about Objective-C's generics, so the best you can do is to return `[Any]`. You can cast them to the correct type at the caller though. If you don't like that, switch to RealmSwift. I don't see what's special about an existing app that stops you from doing that. You don't need to change your old code.

Comment: Are you certain you want to cast live updating realm objects to an array? They will no longer be Realm observable and will no longer live update. Equally as important it also makes them no longer lazily loaded and can consume a large amount of memory with a large dataset (causing a crash).

Comment: Oh, and if you want to cast Realm objects to an array you can just do `let myArray = Array(realmResults)` as it saves having to iterate over the objects

Comment: @Jay i don't belive thats true, the object remains Realm linked as a single instance... putting it in an array doesn't create a non-realm copy... only the fetch result will not update, meaning what objects are returned

Comment: You misunderstood my meaning (probably because my comment was unclear, lol), "They" meaning the Realm Results object (not the internal object), it is no longer live updating so any changes to the results will not be reflected in the array. Also, as mentioned the Results are also no longer lazily loaded (everything is shoved into memory) or Realm observable, however, you can still KVO if needed.

Comment: Yup, that's expected and ok :) for observation i can still attach a notification block to the original RLMResults if desired